# Highcharts - Scatter chart with a line connecting the dots in the series

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to recreate an excel chart using Highcharts.

It's a scatter chart, with the dots for each series connected directly (not a trendline).  This is the example from excel:

[image]

It has to be a scatter charts as the x-axis value are non-periodic (or logarithmic)

Any help gratefully appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

A very helpful Highcharts service team member provided this answer:  http://jsfiddle.net/sc5Gv/4/

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart:{
                type:'scatter'
            },
            plotOptions:{
                scatter:{
                    lineWidth:2
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [[1.5,7], [2.3,9], [4.2,5.6]]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [[0.8,9], [2.1,6.3], [5.0, 10.1]]
            }]
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What kind of problem did you come across, because its default `chart`:

- line http://jsfiddle.net/sc5Gv/2/
- scatter with enabled lineWidth (http://jsfiddle.net/sc5Gv/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Your example doesn't work - as the x-values are periodic (1,2,3,4,...) and need to be fully flexible.

Comment: At the beginning try to set non perdioci data;)

Comment: if you load data dynamically, you'll notice highchart will not set the lineWidth